# Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space. There exists a compact metric space $(Y, d')$ and a map $T:X\to Y$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to $T(X)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

In proving the reverse direction of Prokhorov theorem, I have to prove this auxiliary result. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

> Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space. There exists a compact metric space $(Y, d')$ and a map $T: X \to Y$ such that $T$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $T(X)$.

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y := [0, 1]^\mathbb N$. We define a metric $d'$ on $Y$ by
$$
d'(\xi, \eta) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} | \xi_i - \eta_i|  \quad \forall \xi, \eta \in Y.
$$

The topology induced by $d'$ coincides with the product topology of $Y$. By Tychonoff theorem, $(Y, d')$ is compact. Let $D := \{a_1, a_2,\ldots\}$ be a dense subset of $X$. We define
$$
\alpha_i(x) := \min \{ d(x,a_i), 1\} \quad \forall i \ge 1, x \in X.
$$
Then $\alpha_i:X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous bounded for all $i$. We define $T:X \to Y$ by
$$
T(x) := (\alpha_i(x))_{i\ge 1} \quad \forall x \in X.
$$

Fix $x, y\in X$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$. Then
$$
\min \{ d(x,a_i), 1\} = \min \{ d(y,a_i), 1\} \quad \forall i.
$$

There is a subsequence $\lambda \in \mathbb N^\mathbb N$ such that $a_{\lambda(i)} \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} x$. WLOG, we assume $d(x, a_{\lambda(i)}) <1$ for all $i$. It follows that $d(x, a_{\lambda(i)}) = d(y, a_{\lambda(i)})$ for all $i$. Hence $a_{\lambda(i)} \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} y$. Hence $x=y$ and thus $T$ is injective.

Let $x, x_1,x_2,\ldots \in X$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then $d(x_n, a_i) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} d(x,a_i)$ and thus $\alpha_i(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \alpha_i(x)$ for all $i$.  Product topology is the topology of pointwise convergence, so $T(x_n) \to T(x)$.

Let $x, x_1,x_2,\ldots \in X$ such that $T(x_n) \to T(x)$. Then $\alpha_i(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \alpha_i(x)$ for all $i$. Let $I:=\{i \ge 1 \mid \alpha_i(x) <1\}$. There is a subsequence $\lambda \in I^\mathbb N$ such that

- $\alpha_{\lambda(i)} (x) \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} 0$, and
- $d(x_n, a_{\lambda(i)}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} d(x, a_{\lambda(i)})$ for all $i$.

Hence $a_{\lambda(i)} \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} x$. Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_n d(x_n, x) &\le \lim_n d(x_n, a_{\lambda(i)}) + \lim_n d(a_{\lambda(i)}, x) \\
&=2 d(a_{\lambda(i)}, x) \quad \forall i.
\end{align}
$$

The proof is complete by
$$
\lim_n d(x_n, x) \le 2\lim_i d(a_{\lambda(i)}, x)=0.
$$

Comment: @Zerox : no it's not. That's not a min over $i\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I believe the proof is correct, except that you don't prove $T$ is onto. But don't fix the proof, fix the statement, it doesn't have to be and it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: @justt I could not figure out where the statement goes wrong? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: No actually, the redaction is not great in the latter part. The quantification in $n$ of the statement  "$d(x_n, a_{\lambda(i)}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} d(x, a_{\lambda(i)})$ for all $i$" is fishy. See my answer.

Comment: @justt It seems you have not posted your answer yet :v

Comment: Yep, just finished, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is a quantification/uniformity of convergence problem in the redaction at the end. I would put :

---

Let $x, x_1,x_2,\ldots \in X$ such that $T(x_n) \to T(x)$. Then $\alpha_i(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \alpha_i(x)$ for all $i$. Let $I:=\{i \ge 1 \mid \alpha_i(x) <1\}$. There is a subsequence $\lambda \in I^\mathbb N$ such that $\alpha_{\lambda(i)} (x) \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} 0$.

Let now $n,i \geq 1$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
d(x_n, x) &\le  d(x_n, a_{\lambda(i)}) + d(a_{\lambda(i)}, x) 
\end{align}
$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists an $i\in I$ such that the second term is $<\varepsilon/2$. Now fix this $i$. Since $d(x_n,a_{\lambda(i)}) \to_{n\to\infty} 0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, the first term is $<\varepsilon/2$.

For that choice of $i$, $n_0$ and $n\geq n_0$, we have $d(x_n, x) \le \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$. We have just shown that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\neq n_0$,  $d(x_n,x) \le \varepsilon$. i.e.

$$
\lim_n d(x_n, x) =0.
$$

Comment: But my statement is "... onto $T(X)$". Of course, $T(X)$ is the image of $T$.

Comment: Well that statement is false, sorry. Take $X = {x}$. That's a perfectly valid separable metric space, which can never be homeomorphic to $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Ooooh, I see, the statement does not talk about $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ specifically. Then it works up to a stupid change, I'm updating y answer.

Comment: Well I don't know. I was going to update my answer by simply restricting the codomain of $T$ to $Y' = T(X)$, but in that case $T(X)$ is not necessarily compact, and the statement still doesn't hold.

So I think the statement is wrong. Either change "onto" in "into", either change "compact metric space" in "subset of a compact metric space".

Comment: Case in point : if $X$ is not compact, then it couldn't be homeomorphic to a compact $Y$, as the continuous image of a compact set is compact. So you **have to ** make either of the changes I suggest to the statement, and this is fine anyway for your Prokhorov application.

Comment: Oh, "onto $T(X)$", I see. Then it works and I've been talking nonsense for the past 10 minutes.