# Reverse direction of Prokhorov theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm trying to prove the reverse of Prokhorov theorem. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

---

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set all Borel probability measures on $X$. Let $d_P$ be the [Prokhorov metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434016/can-prokhorov-metric-be-extended-to-all-non-negative-finite-borel-measures) on $\mathcal{P}(X)$. The set $\Gamma \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is called *uniformly tight* if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that
$$
\mu(K^c) := \mu(X\setminus K) \le \varepsilon \quad \forall \mu \in \Gamma.
$$

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is separable, then [$\Gamma$ is uniformly tight] implies [$\Gamma$ is  relatively compact].

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436642/let-x-d-be-a-separable-metric-space-there-exists-a-compact-metric-space)* If $X$ is separable, then there exists a compact metric space $(Y, d')$ and a map $T: X \to Y$ such that $T$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $T(X)$.
>
> *[Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436531/let-d-p-be-the-prokhorov-metric-on-mathcal-px-then-x-d-is-compact-i)* $(X, d)$ is compact if and only if $(\mathcal P, d_P)$ is compact.

By *Lemma 1*, there is a compact metric space $(Y, d')$ and a map $T:X \to Y$ such that $T$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $T(X)$.

Let $(\mu)_n$ be  a sequence in $\overline \Gamma$. Let $\nu_n := T_{\sharp} \mu_n \in \mathcal P(Y)$ for all $n$. Because $(Y, d')$ is compact, so is $(\mathcal P(Y), d'_{P})$ by *Lemma 2*. Hence there exist a subsequence $\lambda \in \mathbb N^\mathbb N$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$ such that $\nu_{\lambda(n)} \to \nu$.

Let $Z := T(X)$. First, we prove that $\nu$ is concentrated on $Z$. Because $\Gamma$ is tight, so is $\overline \Gamma$. For each $m\ge 1$ there is a compact subset $K_m$ of $X$ such that
$$
\mu_n(K_m)  \ge 1-1/m \quad \forall n.
$$

Clearly, $C_m :=T(K_m)$ is compact and thus closed in $Y$. So $C_m \in \mathcal B(Y)$. Because $T$ is injective,
$$
\nu_n (C_m) =  \mu_n(K_m) \ge 1-1/m \quad \forall n.
$$

Also,
$$
\nu(C_m) \ge \limsup_n \nu_n (C_m) \ge 1-1/m.
$$

Then
$$
\nu \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty C_m \right ) \ge 1-1/m  \quad \forall m.
$$

So
$$
\nu \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty C_m \right ) =1.
$$

We define a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ as follows.
$$
\mu (B) := \nu \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left [ T (B )\cap C_m \right ] \right ) \quad \forall B \in \mathcal B(X).
$$

- Notice that homeomorphism sends Borel set to Borel set. Also, $\mathcal B(Z) = \{ C \cap Z \mid C \in  \mathcal B(Y)\}$.
- We have $T(B) \in \mathcal B(Z)$, so $\exists C \in \mathcal B(Y)$ such that $T(B) = C \cap Z$. Hence $T (B )\cap C_m = C \cap Z \cap C_m = C \cap C_m \in \mathcal B(Y)$.
- It follows that $\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left [ T (B )\cap C_m \right ] \in \mathcal B(Y)$ and thus $\mu$ is well-defined.

Next we prove that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$. Because $X$ is separable, it suffices to show that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly. Let $B$ is closed in $X$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\mu(B) &= \nu \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left [ T (B )\cap C_m \right ] \right ) \\
&\ge \limsup_n \nu_n \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left [ T (B )\cap C_m \right ] \right ) \\
&= \limsup_n \mu_n \left (  T^{-1} \left ( \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left [ T (B )\cap C_m \right ] \right ) \right )\\ 
&= \limsup_n \mu_n \left ( B \cap  \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty K_m \right ) \\
&=\limsup_n \mu_n(B).
\end{align}
$$
This completes the proof.